# Security.Stripinaccessible is not working for Deserialized(List<SObject>) from JSON string as Sub query records

Tags: apex, json

Is anyone have solution for below:

A description of the issue, including steps to reproduce and Sample code.
We have stored records of SOQL having sub query as JSON serialized string. On transaction of my Application, JSON string having Sub query records is Deserialized as `List<SObject>` and It is used to check read access by Security.Stripinaccessible method. This is producing unexpected exception like "System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 1166289060-50530 (728051802) (728051802)  67".

Please find below sample code of test method which will be reproduce issue on any org.

```
    @isTest

    public with sharing class TestAPEXcode {

    @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
    public static void testDeserializedSubQueryRecordForFieldAccess(){

        String soql ='SELECT  ID, CurrencyIsoCode, Name, (SELECT ID, Name FROM contacts ORDER BY Name) FROM Account LIMIT 1000';
        
        List<SObject> Accounts = Database.query(soql);
        //List<Account> Accounts = Database.query(soql);

        //Serialized data is stored in one of Custom Object in my app.
        String JSONSObjectQueryRecord = JSON.serializePretty(Accounts); 

        //Deserialized record as JSON string
        List<SObject> deserializedAccounts = (List<SObject>)JSON.deserialize(JSONSObjectQueryRecord, List<SObject>.class);
        //List<Account> deserializeItems = (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(JSONSObjectQueryRecord, List<Account>.class);
        
        SObjectAccessDecision decision = System.Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE, deserializedAccounts);

        if (decision.getRemovedFields().size() > 0 )
        {
            System.Assert(true, 'Read access failed for Fields : ' + decision.getRemovedFields().toString());            
        }      
    }
}
```

Note : Above code is working fine if Record as JSON string has not sub query information.

Stack Strace detail of Exception from Debug log:

> |FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 2137556327-93260 (728051802) (728051802)
> Class.System.Security.stripInaccessible: line 15, column 1
> Class.System.Security.stripInaccessible: line 10, column 1
> Class.AAST1.TestAPEXcode.testDeserializedSubQueryRecordForFieldAccess: line 18, column 1

Comment: Are you sure the records exist and have not been deleted? Did the sub query include the done and size properties? Everything needs to be formatted exactly right or you'll get this kind of error. Can you share your json string?

Comment: Why are you using `(SeeAllData=true)`? Have you tried without?

Comment: @sfdcfox note that you can see from the code that the OP generates the JSON string from query results, so the JSON should be fine (albeit unnecessarily pretty printed). I think the most likely issue relates to the "see all data" as Adrian Larson suggested?

Comment: JSON String of Record: 
[ {
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account",
    "url" : "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Account/0010o00002Bks7UAAR"
  },
  "Id" : "0010o00002Bks7UAAR",
  "CurrencyIsoCode" : "USD",
  "Name" : "GenePoint",
  "Contacts" : {
    "totalSize" : 1,
    "done" : true,
    "records" : [ {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Contact",
        "url" : "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Contact/0030o00002ayrQhAAI"
      },
      "AccountId" : "0010o00002Bks7UAAR",
      "Id" : "0030o00002ayrQhAAI",
      "Name" : "Edna Frank"
    } ]
  }
} ]

Comment: Using test data(Without "(SeeAllData=true)" ) also, I am getting same error. I need "(SeeAllData=true)" for my actual feature implementation. Test is using actual object data from org to validate read access.